# SQL IFELSE Statement To create Sum Variable

Tags: sql, if-statement

```
TABLE 1     
STUDENT TIME    SCORE
1   1   4
1   2   3
1   3   4
2   1   2
2   2   2
2   3   8
3   3   10
3   4   10
4   1   1
4   2   3
4   3   2
4   4   4
4   5   4
4   6   5
```

I have TABLE 1. I wish to group and SUM(SCORE) for each STUDENT and TIME 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 to create this TABLE 2

```
STUDENT TIME    TOTALSCORE
1   1-2 7
1   3-4 4
1   5-6 NA
2   1-2 4
2   3-4 8
2   5-6 NA
3   1-2 NA
3   3-4 20
3   5-6 NA
4   1-2 3
4   3-4 6
4   5-6 4
```

However I have BIG DATA so Wish to start by doing this

```
select DISTINCT(TIME) from TABLE1
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and then basically take all TIME values >= 1 & < 2 as T1; >=2 & < 3 as T2; it matters because we use #.# where the first # is the year and the second # is the trimester. So there are values such as 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 but I don't wish to list that out all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integer math we can use `(time-1)/2` to give us groups of all times between 1-2, 3-4, 5-6, 7-8 etc.

```
select   student
        ,sum(score) as total_score
        ,concat((time+1)/2*2-1, '-', (time+1)/2*2) as semester
from     t
group by student, (time+1)/2
order by student
```

| student | total_score | semester |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1-2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3-4 |
| 2 | 4 | 1-2 |
| 2 | 8 | 3-4 |
| 3 | 20 | 3-4 |
| 4 | 4 | 1-2 |
| 4 | 6 | 3-4 |
| 4 | 9 | 5-6 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jW3A9ELF)

Comment: can you show a way where you take DISTINCT(TIME) and then the SQL to get the values in between? I can show you example

Comment: @bvowe sure. send a fiddle or post a table.

Comment: I add a edit TABLE. Now let us say you want to SUM(SCORE) across TIME_STAMP between the TIME_MESTER values? So you add up all SCORES between 2020-01-01 and 2020-05-31, and 2020-06-01 and 2020-08-30 and so on and so forth?

Comment: @bvowe what does TIME_MESTER represent? if it's a semester then why do you have na at the end? does it correlate to the info in the other columns? You should accept my answer as it answers the question you presented (I updated it to give you the semester as well) and then clean your table and ask another question (which I will answer).

Comment: it represents the range of END values for the semester and it is NA because I just create a truncate table to show all of the values. And So basically I wish to sum up the student score across the date windows for TIME_MESTER (the ranges) using the actual TIME values. This is clear?

Comment: please see new question

Comment: @bvowe I see it. I'll do it right now.